# How can I make a ggplot2 barplot showing the number of ones and twos in my data frame colum?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame df has two columns, a and b.

I'd like to make a ggplot2 barplot for column b with two bars. The first bar of height 3 (because b has three ones) and a second bar of height 2 (because b has two twos).

How can I do this? If data=df, what are x and y in `aes`?

```
df = data.frame(a = c(6,3,8,7,9), b = c(1,1,2,2,1))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=?, y=?)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image: desired plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the frequency of values from 'b' with [`count`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html) which returns a summarised output with the unique values of 'b' and a new column 'n' with frequency.  In the `aes`, specify the `x` as 'b' and `y` as 'n'

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
    count(b = factor(b)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = b, y = n)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `x = b` in `geom_bar` -

```
library(ggplot2)

df$b <- factor(df$b)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=b)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]